# how to print elements pointed by iterator type list<pair<int,int>>::iterator it

Tags: c++, stl, iterator

i need to print the second element of the pair of the each block in the list. Any guidance will be appreciated please help?

Comment: i'm traversing through the list..

Comment: i tried cout<<fit.second;

Comment: `fit->second;` which is the same as `(*fit).second;`

Answer (score 4):

Each iterator in your list points to an object of type `std::pair<int, int>`. In order to print the second element in the pair object using iterator `itr` do this:

```
std::cout << itr->second;
```